# Need help on Java Swing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, panel, grid-layout, border-layout

I'm very new to Swing and I need to build a `JFrame` that:

- Has an image on top.
- Below the image has 16 little images divided into 4 groups (4 "panels"), on the same "row".
- Below those 16 images I need 4 "panels" on the same "row". Every panel contains some horizontal scrollable images (of the same size).
- Below those 4 "panels" I need two "panels" on the same "row". The left one contains some horizontal scrollable images (of the same size), the right one a `JList` (or something like that: scrollable text rows).
- Below those 2 "panels" i need 4 "panels" on the same "row". Every one contains 4 rows of text.

How can I create a `JFrame` like this? I tried using only `BorderLayout`s and `GridLayout`s but I don't know how to divide the `GridLayouts` in other `GridLayouts` (Don't even know if it's possible).

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problems are you having when you code the above paragraph? By "panel" do you mean `JPanel`?

Comment: I tried to create the frame "step-by-step". So I created the "first row", that contains a big image. Now I was trying to add the others, but realized that I don't know how to structure the frame at all. By "panel" i mean a JPanel, yes.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: It is too long, but I just need help on HOW to structure a frame like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one panel and add it to frame, set `layout(GridLayout(6,1))`. Then you can create classes or methods and extend it to JPanel and create each panel. And after try to add all this panels to you main panel in The frame.

I don't know if I understood correctly what you want, this is solution I found.